# Using regex to match location with optional sublocation

Tags: regex, url

I want to redirect `/spam/(.*)` to `/$1` (including `/spam/` to `/`) and `/spam` to `/`, but not `/spam(.*)` to `$1` or `/$1`.

So `/spam/eggs/bacon` becomes `/eggs/bacon`, `/spam/` and `/spam` both become `/`, and `spameggs/bacon` does not become `eggs/bacon`.

What regular expression `(chars)` to `$1` pair accomplishes this?

Comment: It would help if you specified what regex environment you need this (.NET, PHP, Perl, ...) since behavior might be a bit different

Comment: @latkin it's for a URL rewrite directive in an nginx config file, but I've also wanted a solution for Python's `re` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern: `/spam(?:/(.*)|()$)`

Replace: `/$1`

This will replace correctly, is the simplest of the solutions posted so far, and has the added bonus that the match will fail if the path is not of the form you are considering (i.e. if it doesn't match `/spam` or `/spam/___)`

Comment: In some environment `$2` can be undefined.

Comment: Good point, I have asked OP for clarification.  I've also edited to handle this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple: `^.*((?<=^/spam/).*|(?<=^/spam))$` to `/$1`

*[Test](http://ideone.com/YqAAA) (http://ideone.com/YqAAA):*

```
'/spam'          --> '/'
'/spam/'         --> '/'
'/spam/one'      --> '/one'
'/spam/one/two'  --> '/one/two'
```

Comment: /spam/eggs will map to //eggs

Comment: Works now, though I would contend you are stretching "pretty simple" :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the RegExp flavor, but I would try something like…

`/(spam($|/))?(.*)` ==> `/$3`

Here's a PHP example.

```
$rx = '~/(spam($|/))?(.*)~';
$arr = array(
    '/spam',
    '/spam/',
    '/spam/eggs/bacon',
    'spameggs/bacon',
    '/spameggs/bacon'
);
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    echo "<b>Before:</b> $val\n<b>After:</b> " . preg_replace($rx,'/$3',$val) . PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
}
```

outputs

> **Before:** /spam
> **After:** /
>
> **Before:** /spam/
> **After:** /
>
> **Before:** /spam/eggs/bacon
> **After:** /eggs/bacon
>
> **Before:** spameggs/bacon
> **After:** spameggs/bacon
>
> **Before:** /spameggs/bacon
> **After:** /spameggs/bacon

Comment: That will map /spam/eggs to //eggs, /spam/ to //, and it matches illegal stuff like /spameggs

Comment: It still matches illegal paths

Comment: @latkin Just tried it in PHP, and the given examples returned the desired results. Can you give an example to those illegal paths?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, this will work for replacement purposes.  I was thinking the OP didn't even want the match to be successful on paths which don't adhere to his pattern.